# Set User Time Zone by GPO on Windows Server 2012

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, timezone

I am trying to set the time zone of users in Windows Server 2012 by using a user GPO.

To be more precise, I have an application which users can log into by RDP, what I am trying to do is when they log in to set the time zone of their locale. The server could be in the UK, Europe, or the US, but users could be anywhere, and what I want to do is set the time zone of their locale and not the time zone of the location of the server.

Answer (score 5):

Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Device and Resource Redirection

set Allow time zone redirection to enable.

Apply that GPO to the OU/Container where the server is located.